# Is it possible to create rasa 2.0 chatbot which trains itself on the basis of user input?

Tags: chatbot, rasa

Is it possible to create a rasa chatbot which trains itself on the basis of user input?

If yes, please suggest me some resources.

Answer (score 0):

The experimental features end-to-end training was recently released in Rasa 2.2

This allows training a model on actual user text and bot responses.

More info [here](https://forum.rasa.com/t/end-to-end-training-experimental/38158).